# SQL Server 2014 SSMS System Tables missing Columns Folder

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I'm giving up!

I installed SQL Server 2014 SP1 with SSMS and I am not able to see the Index and Columns Folder in the Object Explorer for the System tables.

If I am using the SSMS 2012 or even the new SSMS 2016 everything is fine, even a complete new installation of SQL Server 2014 didn't solve the problem.

I found different articles about some issues with SSMS 2014 but now I am patched up to 12.0.4439 with the SSMS ... still the same problem.

The funny thing is that even the `Select Top 1000 Rows` and `Edit Top 200 Rows` are greyed out.

Please help me Captain ... it already took me nearly 2 days

Comment: I've just checked and I don't see these either in my SSMS 2014. I do in SSMS 2016 CTP3 though. Maybe this was by design? In any event why is this a big issue for you?

Comment: I am testing and implementing CDC and i need to track the columns for the synchronization

Comment: The SSMS preview releases support SQL Server versions from SQL Server 2008 all the way to SQL Server 2016. If the preview release is working, I'd probably just stick with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same like Cpt. Monac mentioned !
I installed SSMS preview to cover all different SQL Server Versions.
The column and index folders are visible again so I am able to mess around with CDC